# ResultSets can not divide received lists

Tags: mybatis

I have two ResultSets that both of theme has completely separated `SELECT` and has not any relation to each other. but `MyBatis` always try to mix the result.

### Movie table

| ID_ | NAME_ | YEAR_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Movie1 | 2020 |
| 2 | Movie2 | 2008 |
| 3 | Movie3 | 1988 |

### Artist table

| ID_ | NAME_ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jane |

**Select:**

```xml
<select id="selectMultiple" resultSets="movies,artists" resultMap="multipleQueriesResult" statementType="CALLABLE">
    BEGIN
      SELECT M.ID_         AS mId,
             M.NAME_       AS mName,
             M.YEAR_       AS mYear
      FROM TestMyBatis.dbo.Movie AS M
    END
    BEGIN
      SELECT A.ID_   AS aId,
             A.NAME_ AS aName
      FROM TestMyBatis.dbo.Artist AS A
    END
  </select>
```

**ResultMap:**

```xml
<resultMap id="multipleQueriesResult" type="DivideOut" autoMapping="true">

    <collection property="movie"
                ofType="Movie"
                javaType="list"
                resultSet="movies">
      <id property="id" column="mId"/>
      <result property="name" column="mName"/>
      <result property="year" column="mYear"/>
    </collection>

    <collection property="artist"
                ofType="Artist"
                javaType="list"
                resultSet="artists">
      <id property="id" column="aId"/>
      <result property="name" column="aName"/>
    </collection>
  </resultMap>
```

**DivideOut:**

```java
public class DivideOut {

  public List<Object> movie;
  public List<Object> artist;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "DivideOut{" +
      "movie=" + movie +
      ", artist=" + artist +
      '}';
  }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
DivideOut{movie=[Movie{id=1, name=Movie1, year=2020}], artist=[Artist{id=1, name='john}]}, 
DivideOut{movie=[Movie{id=1, name=Movie1, year=2020}], artist=[Artist{id=2, name='jane}]},  
DivideOut{movie=[Movie{id=2, name=Movie2, year=2008}], artist=[Artist{id=1, name='john}]},  
DivideOut{movie=[Movie{id=2, name=Movie2, year=2008}], artist=[Artist{id=2, name='jane}]},  
DivideOut{movie=[Movie{id=3, name=Movie3, year=1988}], artist=[Artist{id=1, name='jane}]},  
DivideOut{movie=[Movie{id=3, name=Movie3, year=1988}], artist=[Artist{id=2, name='john}]}
]
```

**Actual Output:**

```
[
DivideOut{id=1, name=Movie1, year=2020, artist=[Artist{id=1, name='john}]}, 
DivideOut{id=1, name=Movie1, year=2020, artist=[Artist{id=2, name='jane}]}, 
DivideOut{id=2, name=Movie2, year=2008, artist=[Artist{id=1, name='john}]},
DivideOut{id=2, name=Movie2, year=2008, artist=[Artist{id=2, name='jane}]},
DivideOut{id=3, name=Movie3, year=1988, artist=[Artist{id=1, name='john}]},
DivideOut{id=3, name=Movie3, year=1988, artist=[Artist{id=2, name='jane}]}
]
```

Records of `Movie` is 3 and records of `Artist` is 2.

`Artist` and `Movie` records should be in **separated** lists, but they are **mix**.

Database is `MSSQLSERVER` **2016** and Driver `JDBC.SQLServerDriver` **11.2.0**

Comment: Please add DB and driver versions.

Comment: @ave added in question.

Comment: I have added a few example rows for each table. Could you fill out the "expected output" section? I couldn't understand the relationship between `DivideOut` and `movie` field.

Comment: @ave I changed some things in the issue as you said.

Comment: So...there is always only one item in `movie` and `artist` even though they are `List`? And you expect 6 `DivideOut` instances because... 2 (rows in `Movie` table) x 3 (rows in `Artist` table) = 6?

Comment: @ave No it's not. maybe it has multiple items. the main issue is to separating List of object from each other, but always the first set (here is movie) mixing the second set (artist) in its other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result map maps the query result to `DivideOut` object, so the first key question is "How many `DivideOut` instances do you expect?".
It seems that you just need two independent lists and don't care about `DivideOut`, so I assumed the answer is 1.

In the following statement, I added an extra query and named the result set `dummy`.
This extra query returns one row that creates the single `DivideOut` instance.

```sql
<select id="selectMultiple" resultSets="dummy,movies,artists"
  resultMap="multipleQueriesResult" statementType="CALLABLE">
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1
  END
  BEGIN
    SELECT
           M.ID_         AS mId,
           M.NAME_       AS mName,
           M.YEAR_       AS mYear
    FROM Movie AS M
  END
  BEGIN
    SELECT A.ID_   AS aId,
           A.NAME_ AS aName
    FROM Artist AS A
  END
</select>
```

If you just want two independent lists, it probably is better to 1) execute two independent SELECTs or 2) specify two result maps like [this test](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/0c9f887141/src/test/java/org/apache/ibatis/submitted/sptests/SPMapper.xml#L111-L114).

Here is an executable demo:
https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-73685798